# Can I register a file in the distributed cache during FlatMapFunction in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a FlatMapFunction that lists items in S3. I want to register each item in the distributed file cache.

Is that even possible?

ie, in my job:

```
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

...

... = myDataSet.flatMap(new S3Lister(env));
```

and in the `S3Lister` file:

```
...
String id = os.getKey().substring(os.getKey().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
env.registerCachedFile("s3://" + bucket + os.getKey(), id);
...
```

and then later access it from the distributed cache in another custom coGroup function.

Could this work? Are you even allowed to pass the ExecutionEnvironment around like that?

**Update**:

If not, what's the best way to get an entire S3 bucket into a distributed file cache for use in a flink job?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, registerCachedFiles method helps to upload the files when submitting the job. So it's not possible to call it in a deployed program.

But from your description, why not read the S3 files directly?

Comment: I guess the answer to that is specific to my job. I have two file caches on S3. I'm coGrouping them and running a match function across them. If I get the content from before the coGroup, the size of the data explodes during the coGroup. If I get the content during the match function, it would result in a LOT of S3 GETs, so: $$$.

I guess what I need to do then is list the files from S3 not using the flink API and register them in the cache like that?

Comment: Maybe what I need to know is: what's the best way to get an entire S3 bucket into a distributed file cache for use in a flink job?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reach functions and instead of normal ones, and then load your distributed cache in it.

First you load your file:

```
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

// register a file from HDFS
env.registerCachedFile("hdfs:///path/to/your/file", "hdfsFile")

// register a local executable file (script, executable, ...)
env.registerCachedFile("file:///path/to/exec/file", "localExecFile", true)

// define your program and execute
...
DataSet<String> input = ...
DataSet<Integer> result = input.map(new MyMapper());
...
env.execute();
```

and then use it in you ReachFunction class:

```
// extend a RichFunction to have access to the RuntimeContext
public final class MyMapper extends RichMapFunction<String, Integer> {

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {

      // access cached file via RuntimeContext and DistributedCache
      File myFile = getRuntimeContext().getDistributedCache().getFile("hdfsFile");
      // read the file (or navigate the directory)
      ...
    }

    @Override
    public Integer map(String value) throws Exception {
      // use content of cached file
      ...
    }
}
```

You can see these in [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/#distributed-cache) Flink Documentation.